# JED Checker - Rule Jamss - JAMSS - Joomla! Anti-Malware Scan Script

Tags: joomla-3.x, security, jed

I am receiving an alert in JED Checker, the line of code that generates the alert contains `str_replace` which is used to replace of spaces with hyphens.

Here the code:

```
$uniqueFilter = array_unique($unique_filter);
foreach ($uniqueFilter as $filter) {
    echo '<a href="#" class="filter-item" data-group=".'.str_replace(' ', '-', $filter).'">'.$filter.'</a>';
}
```

I would like to know if `str_replace` or `preg_replace` is a danger and why they have it marked to generate an alert.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an unnecessarily strict rule and it has already been removed in code base. The change should be reflected in the next major JED Checker release. See this [commit](https://github.com/joomla-extensions/jedchecker/commit/fa5eb52dd6c5ab34cdfb697cfd5b1c8c2e966ee2) for reference.

Comment: I often use `strstr()` in production code.  Why is it blacklisted.  Who came up with `[\s/\*\w\W\(]`? I'd like to hear what their intention was. That subpattern reveals a lack of regex understanding.

Answer (score 2):

Keep in mind that:

- [https://github.com/btoplak/Joomla-Anti-Malware-Scan-Script--JAMSS-/blob/master/README.md#:~:text=this%20script%20gives%20out%20many%20false,%20so%20be%20cautious](https://github.com/btoplak/Joomla-Anti-Malware-Scan-Script--JAMSS-/blob/master/README.md#:%7E:text=this%20script%20gives%20out%20many%20false,%20so%20be%20cautious) says:

  > this script gives out many false-positive files, as it is not "ironed out" yet, so be cautious
- https://github.com/btoplak/Joomla-Anti-Malware-Scan-Script--JAMSS-/blob/master/README.md#status says:

  > BETA - This is a "work in progress" so let me know if you have any problems, found bug, have questions or wish to help in some way.

**That said, I must assume that the script doesn't like that you aren't calling `htmlspecialchars()`** on a variable being printed into an html document. Have a read of https://stackoverflow.com/q/4882307/2943403 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/46491/2943403. I don't see any potential vulnerability in executing that very trivial string manipulation with `str_replace()` -- I think this is a [red herring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_herring).

If you, yourself, are worried about this being an attack vector, then you should sanitise the string as much as possible.  Will it contain only letters?  letters and numbers? any allowed symbols?  A regex to strip unwelcome characters could be a good idea.

I might code it like this:

```
foreach (array_unique($unique_filter) as $filter) {
    printf(
        '<a href="#" class="filter-item" data-group="%s">%s</a>',
        htmlspecialchars(str_replace(' ', '-', $filter)),
        htmlspecialchars($filter)
    );
}
```

This way you:

- keep the code width short and
- eliminate the single-use variable `$uniqueFilter` and
- eliminate the noise of concatenating of text and function calls

Comment: Thank you, sorry for my English. I tried using `htmlspecialchars`, even pasting the full code, but the alert continues. I am converting Joomla tag and category names to classes. I know it is a false alert, what I would like is to know if `str_replace` is dangerous as described in JAMSS

Comment: I will urge you to move the green tick to Sharky's answer because it is correct and supported by documented evidence.  If you gained helpful insights from my answer, then an upvote on my answer is sufficient acknowledgement.

Comment: Also keep in mind that the JAMSS script has not been updated for 7 years... Security is not a one shot deal...